# What is this short plant with spiky leaves and yellow flowers that turn orange/red?

Tags: identification, weeds

Located near Chicago, IL, USA

This plant started growing around July and a month later produced some yellow flowers. It seems that the flowers turn orange when they are dying. It is about 1 foot tall. It has small thorns on the edge of its leaves.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *Carthamus tinctorius* or safflower. If you didn't plant it, it's probably grown from a seed dropped by birds. It's an annual plant, and is grown as a crop for the safflower oil which can be extracted. All sorts of information on this plant  here  https://owlcation.com/stem/Safflower-Uses-A-Vegetable-Oil-A-Dye-and-Insulin-For-Diabetics